# How to set button selection and unselection image?

Tags: image, ios6, uibutton

when i am touch the button to show selected image and again touch that button unselection image shown.

I am try this coding:

```
UIButton *btn=(UIButton*) sender;
if (btn.selected=YES)
{        
    [btn setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"reportsel.png"]  forState:UIControlStateSelected];

}else{        

    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reports.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Anytime click this button not   went to else condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Highlighted state, use:
[btnObj setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgName.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

In Normal State, use:
[btnObj setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgName1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: highlighted state its working....selected state am using this code:  UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)sender;
    if (btn.selected=YES)
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reportsel.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    }else{
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reports.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } its only showing the selection image not unselection image

Comment: i got the ouptut using this         if ([sender isSelected]) {
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reports.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [sender setSelected:NO];
        }else {
            [sender setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"reportsel.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [sender setSelected:YES];
        }